# How to make VSIX installer to register assembly automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix, regasm

I have developed a custom code generator and deploy it via a VSIX, the problem is I should register assembly via regasm.exe after installing VSIX, but I have seen some projects such as DSLTool with custom code generation that registers automatically, any body knows how can I have automatically registration in my VSIX project?

Comment: I've found "Register for COM interop" option in project properties window, in Build tab, it seems that this is the solution but after setting I get this error 
    "Error 3 The assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe /tlb. DslPackage"

Comment: I edited my answer to make sure this build setting gets removed, along with other COM-related elements that are no longer required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

### 0. Remove old (bad practice) COM code

1. Edit your project build settings to *not* have "Register for COM interop" checked.
2. Edit your **AssemblyInfo.cs** and set `ComVisible` to `false`:

   ```
   [assembly: ComVisible(false)]
   ```
3. Assuming your generator is named `MyCodeGenerator`, open the definition of `MyCodeGenerator` and add the attribute:

   ```
   [ComVisible(true)]
   ```

### 1. Edit your VSIX project to enable generation of a pkgdef file.

1. Right click your project in **Solution Explorer** and select **Unload Project**.
2. Right click the unloaded project and select **Edit *MyProject*.csproj**, where *MyProject* is the name of your project.
3. Locate the XML element `<GeneratePkgDefFile>`.

   1. If the element exists, ensure that its value is set to `true`.
   2. Otherwise, add the following to the end of the first `<PropertyGroup>` element in your project file which *does not* have a `Condition` attribute (this is almost always the first `PropertyGroup` in the file).

      ```
      <GeneratePkgDefFile>true</GeneratePkgDefFile>
      ```
4. Repeat step 3 to set `<CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>` to `true`.
5. Save and close the **.csproj** file.
6. Right click the unloaded project in **Solution Explorer** and select **Reload Project**.
7. Open your project's **source.extension.vsixmanifest** file and locate the `<Content>` element. Add the following element as a child:

   ```
   <VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%|</VsPackage>
   ```

   If your extension does not provide any other content elements, the entire `<Content>` element would now be this:

   ```
   <Content>
     <VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%|</VsPackage>
   </Content>
   ```

### 2. Define the required attribute types

At the end of this answer are sections for **ProvideGeneratorAttribute.cs** and **ProvideAssemblyObjectAttribute.cs**. Add these files to your project.

### 3. Register the code generator class

1. Open your project's **AssemblyInfo.cs**.
2. Assuming your custom code generator class is named `MyCodeGenerator`, add the following attribute to the assembly info file.

   ```
   [assembly: ProvideAssemblyObject(typeof(MyCodeGenerator))]
   ```

### 4. Associate your code generator with the language service

1. Open your project's **AssemblyInfo.cs**.
2. Assuming your custom code generator class is named `MyCodeGenerator`, and you want to register the code generator with the C# language service, add the following attribute to the assembly info file.

   ```
   [assembly: ProvideGenerator(
       typeof(MyCodeGenerator),
       VSConstants.UICONTEXT.CSharpProject_string,
       Description = "Description of the generator",
       GeneratesDesignTimeSource = true)]
   ```

### Appendix A: ProvideGeneratorAttribute.cs

**Disclaimer: This code is completely untested.**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ProvideGeneratorAttribute : RegistrationAttribute
{
    private readonly Type _generatorType;
    private readonly Guid _languageServiceGuid;
    private string _name;
    private string _description;
    private bool _generatesDesignTimeSource;

    public ProvideGeneratorAttribute(Type generatorType, string languageServiceGuid)
    {
        if (generatorType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("generatorType");
        if (languageServiceGuid == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("languageServiceGuid");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(languageServiceGuid))
            throw new ArgumentException("languageServiceGuid cannot be empty");

        _generatorType = generatorType;
        _languageServiceGuid = new Guid(languageServiceGuid);
        _name = _generatorType.Name;
    }

    public Type GeneratorType
    {
        get
        {
            return _generatorType;
        }
    }

    public Guid LanguageServiceGuid
    {
        get
        {
            return _languageServiceGuid;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new ArgumentException("value cannot be empty");

            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }

        set
        {
            _description = value;
        }
    }

    public bool GeneratesDesignTimeSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _generatesDesignTimeSource;
        }

        set
        {
            _generatesDesignTimeSource = value;
        }
    }

    private string RegistrationKey
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(@"Generators\{0}\{1}", LanguageServiceGuid.ToString("B"), Name);
        }
    }

    public override void Register(RegistrationContext context)
    {
        using (Key key = context.CreateKey(RegistrationKey))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
                key.SetValue(string.Empty, Description);
            key.SetValue("CLSID", GeneratorType.GUID.ToString("B"));
            key.SetValue("GeneratesDesignTimeSource", GeneratesDesignTimeSource ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    public override void Unregister(RegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.RemoveKey(RegistrationKey);
    }
}
```

### Appendix B: ProvideAssemblyObjectAttribute.cs

**Disclaimer: This code is completely untested.**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class ProvideAssemblyObjectAttribute : RegistrationAttribute
{
    private readonly Type _objectType;
    private RegistrationMethod _registrationMethod;

    public ProvideAssemblyObjectAttribute(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("objectType");

        _objectType = objectType;
    }

    public Type ObjectType
    {
        get
        {
            return _objectType;
        }
    }

    public RegistrationMethod RegistrationMethod
    {
        get
        {
            return _registrationMethod;
        }

        set
        {
            _registrationMethod = value;
        }
    }

    private string ClsidRegKey
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(@"CLSID\{0}", ObjectType.GUID.ToString("B"));
        }
    }

    public override void Register(RegistrationContext context)
    {
        using (Key key = context.CreateKey(ClsidRegKey))
        {
            key.SetValue(string.Empty, ObjectType.FullName);
            key.SetValue("InprocServer32", context.InprocServerPath);
            key.SetValue("Class", ObjectType.FullName);
            if (context.RegistrationMethod != RegistrationMethod.Default)
                _registrationMethod = context.RegistrationMethod;

            switch (RegistrationMethod)
            {
            case Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationMethod.Default:
            case Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationMethod.Assembly:
                key.SetValue("Assembly", ObjectType.Assembly.FullName);
                break;

            case Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationMethod.CodeBase:
                key.SetValue("CodeBase", context.CodeBase);
                break;

            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            key.SetValue("ThreadingModel", "Both");
        }
    }

    public override void Unregister(RegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.RemoveKey(ClsidRegKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much,It works, but I used built-in ProvideCodeGeneratorAttribute instead of ProvideGeneratorAttribute

Comment: Tested on VS2019 with built-in ProvideCodeGeneratorAttribute - "Cannot find custom tool XYZ on this system"; it doesn't work regardles of how ComVisible is used. I guess it does require regasm registration...