# Make VSIX package automation object COM visible withou manual Regasm regestration

Tags: c#, com, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm working on a visual studio package that could provide automation object, which later could be used in third-party applications through COM and DTE.GetObject(string name) calls.

For this, I've created the following setup.
In a visual studio instance I have the following VSIX package running.

```
namespace CustomAutomationObjectProvider
{
    [Guid("5B152019-535C-4602-9084-3F5250118A7D")]
    public interface ICustomAutomationObject
    {
        string GetCustomString();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class CustomAutomationObject : ICustomAutomationObject
    {
        public string GetCustomString()
        {
            return "Hello from automation object!";
        }
    }
    
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [Guid("61C27A04-A031-4DF6-8E48-0B4BFEB8F49B")]
    [ProvideAutomationObject("CustomAutomationObject")]
    public sealed class AutomationObjectProvider : AsyncPackage
    {
        private CustomAutomationObject _instance;

        protected override object GetAutomationObject(string name)
        {
            if(name == "CustomAutomationObject")
            {
                if(_instance == null)
                {
                     _instance = new CustomAutomationObject();
                }
            }
            
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

In a third-party application, I'm connecting to instance of visual studio, getting its DTE object, and trying to get this automation object like this. I'm able to get some object from GetObject call, but I'm unable to cast it to the target interface - it fails with E_NOINTERFACE

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    ...
    ...

    var customAutomationObjectRaw = DTE.GetObject("CustomAutomationObject");
    var customAutomationObject = (CustomAutomationObjectProvider.ICustomAutomationObject)customAutomationObjectRaw;
}
```

I think I might miss some COM visibility setup in my solution or VSIX package configuration but I can't find any information on it. I'm able to register assembly manualy with regasm.exe, but based on this thread
[How to make VSIX installer to register assembly automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634899/how-to-make-vsix-installer-to-register-assembly-automatically) I assume there should be a way to do it automatically. Also, I was mainly using this one as a reference https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/blob/main/Python/Product/Profiling/PythonProfilingPackage.cs

Comment: Smells like an out-of-process scenario, getting 'Register for COM interop' to work is essential.  The type library needs to be registered so the object can be marshalled across process boundaries.  "returns errors" doesn't help us help you, run Regasm.exe with the /codebase and /tlb options from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated my question, added error and reason why I thought that I shouldn't use regasm.exe, but definitely will give it a try.

Comment: After figuring out couple of issues I was able to register the assembly with regasm and it forks fine, but I still think there should be an automatic way to do it. Updated question accordingly.